# How much stack space do MPI calls require?

Tags: c++, stack, mpi

I am writing a code that combines the use of the Message Passing Interface (MPI) and qthreads. I am having to use a larger than default stack size (8KB as opposed to 4KB) even though my actual code uses well under 1 KB per qthread. I believe that the MPI calls are the cause of the stack overflow.

The code uses OpenMPI and qthreads from Sandia National Laboratories.

The code runs with a single qthread "shepherd" on each MPI process, using qthread_init(1) - qthreads is used only for context switching within an MPI process.

My questions are:
1) Is there a way to determine how much stack space an MPI call will use?
2) Is there a way to reduce how much stack space it uses?
3) Are there particular MPI calls that use a larger amount of stack space than average MPI calls?

Answer (score 0):

There are profiling tools for this, google `mpi profiling` I would recommend [mpip](http://mpip.sourceforge.net) since its easy to setup. Also [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.mpiwrap) has a section on debugging mpi and parallel programs. If these don't identity the problem you will have to dig deeper into performance tuning and play around with [message sizes](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi_performance/) and such.

Answer (score 0):

MPI can be called from Pthreads, which have something like an 8 MB default stack size. In practice, I think it's under 1 KB, with large temps allocated on the heap.